# Alexa and Python Lambda Function to retrieve Device Address

Tags: python, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to get the device address from Alexa.

I've followed [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html) tutorial but I'm having some problems.

The code I'm using is this one:

```
def test_intent(event, context):
   from botocore.vendored import requests

   device_id = event["context"]["System"]["device"]["deviceId"]
   api_access_token = event["context"]["System"]["apiAccessToken"]

   api_uri = "https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/devices/{}/settings/address".format(device_id)
   api_headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(api_access_token)}

   api_response = requests.get(api_uri, headers=api_headers)
   data = api_response.json()
```

I put some location (US location) in my alexa app and I allowed the permission the skill ask me (Full Address in this case).

The api_response.status_code is 204, so it should be ok. But when I run the last line "api_response.json()" it crashes (alexa replays that there is a problem with the skill).

I think the problem is the api_response is None and the json is not working, but I don't know why this could happend.

Any guess about this?

Edit:
After some test, I realised that I've set the phone's location, not the echo dot location in the Alexa app, so that's the reason the app responded with 204 (no data)

Comment: `api_response` isn't `None` if you can verify `api_response.status_code` is 204. How, exactly, does it crash? Is there a traceback, and if so, what is it?

Comment: I'm testing it talking with alexa, because I cannot use the Alexa Skill Test because it doesn't have a DeviceId.
So when I comment the line "data = api_response.json()" the flow continues, but when I uncomment that line, Alexa replies "There is a problem with the request's skill response"

Comment: Alexa isn't giving enough information to debug the problem.

Comment: No :( Maybe I don't know how to debug it, but I'm sure that the amazon skill command line doesn't work with the device location :S